# Printing temperature to LCD outside loop

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm new to Arduino or coding in general and I'm trying some things. I'm using code for a basic menu that you can scroll through with a button press. This works fine but I want it to display the temperature on the first menu.

The code for calculating the temperature is in the loop() while the code for customizing the menu's is before `setup()` and `loop()`. I want to print the temperature to the LCD using `lcd.print(temperatureC)` but `temperatureC` cannot be used since it's only declared in loop().

Is there any way I can work around this? I'm very new to this.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8,9,10,11,12,13);
int tempPin = A0;
int photocellPin = A1;
const byte mySwitch = 7;
#define aref_voltage 3.3


// these "states" are what screen is currently being displayed.
typedef enum 
  {
  POWER_ON, TEMPERATURE, LIGHTSENSOR, EXHAUST_FAN1, EXHAUST_FAN2,
  // add more here ...

  LAST_STATE  // have this last
  } states;

byte state = POWER_ON;

byte oldSwitch = HIGH;

void powerOn ()
  {
  Serial.println ("Welcome!");
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Welcome!");
  delay(2000);

  }

void showTemperature ()
  {
  Serial.println ("Temperature");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Temperature");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(temperatureC);



void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Start the serial connection with the computer
                       //to view the result open the serial monitor 
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  pinMode (mySwitch, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  powerOn ();
}

void loop()
{ 
  int sensorVal = analogRead(tempPin);
  delay(5);
  int photocellVal = analogRead(photocellPin);
  delay(5);
  float voltage = (sensorVal) * aref_voltage;
  voltage /= 1024.0; 
  float temperatureC = (voltage - .5) * 100;
  temperatureC = round(temperatureC * 2.0) / 2.0;

  {
  byte switchValue = digitalRead (mySwitch);

  // detect switch presses
  if (switchValue != oldSwitch)
    {
    delay (100);   // debounce

    // was it pressed?
    if (switchValue == LOW)
      {
      state++;      // next state
      if (state >= LAST_STATE)
        state = TEMPERATURE;  

      switch (state)
        {
        case POWER_ON:     powerOn ();         break;
        case TEMPERATURE:  showTemperature (); break;
        case LIGHTSENSOR:  showLightsensor (); break;
        case EXHAUST_FAN1: showExhaustFan1 (); break;
        case EXHAUST_FAN2: showExhaustFan2 (); break;
        }  // end of switch
      }  // end of switch being pressed

    oldSwitch = switchValue;  
    } // end of switch changing state

  }  // end of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to read the temperature into a method on its own, (Separate from the light reading code - make another method for this)...

```
float getTemperature() {
  int sensorVal = analogRead(tempPin);
  delay(5);
  float voltage = (sensorVal) * aref_voltage;
  voltage /= 1024.0; 
  float temperatureC = (voltage - .5) * 100;
  temperatureC = round(temperatureC * 2.0) / 2.0;
  return temperatureC;
}
```

Then call this method in your showTemperature() method.